# How to collapse a responsive vertical menu (hide-show) after click on an item?

Tags: jquery, menu, show-hide

My page is divided in 2 sides: left for the menu and right for hidden divs.
It's a responsive site so on mobiles the menu collapse.
Well, all perfect in any device! But ... the list menu is very long. Perfect for PC or tablet screens but in the mobile it fills all the screen so when you click on an item it looks nothing happens (of course! the hidden div is under the menu, outside the screen!) Only scrolling you can see the div!
Well, I tried but I'm not able to collapse the menu after click on an item (so you can immediately see the div on mobile.) It collapse and expand only clicking on the title.
I tried but the only result I had is to collapse the menu also in the wide screen (and of course is not what I want! You need to reload again the page to see the menu).
Can please someone help me to make the script as I need?
Here is my sample html and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Settori d'intervento</title>
<link href="Assets/settoriTEST.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var collapsed = true;
  $('nav2>h2').click(function() {
    collapsed = !collapsed;
    formatSidebar();
  });
  $(window).resize(formatSidebar);
  formatSidebar();

  function formatSidebar() {
    if ($(window).width() > 766) {
      $('nav2').removeClass('collapsible');
      $('nav2 #menuSX').show();
    } else {
      $('nav2').addClass('collapsible');
      if (collapsed) { 
        $('nav2 #menuSX').hide();
        $('nav2 > h2').removeClass('minus');
      } else {
        $('nav2 #menuSX').show();
        $('nav2 > h2').addClass('minus');
      }
    }
  };
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menubox").hide();
$(".menubox:first").hide();

    $(".menuitem").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".menubox").hide();
        var relatedDivID = $(this).attr('href');

        $("" + relatedDivID).fadeToggle("slow","linear"); 
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs div').hide();
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
$('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
$('#tabs div').hide();
$(currentTab).show();
return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="content">
  <div id="hide_show">
    <nav2>
      <h2>Menù </h2>
      <div id="menuSX">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="menuitem" href="#A">A</a></li>
          <li><a class="menuitem" href="#B">B</a></li>
          <li><a class="menuitem" href="#C">C</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav2>
    <div id="Content3">
      <div class="menubox" id="A">
        <h2>A</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="menubox" id="B">
        <h2>B</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="menubox" id="C">
        <h2>C</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
nav2 ul, nav2 ol {list-style: none; list-style-image: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
nav2.collapsible > h2 {
    background-color: #657A81;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menuitem {
    display: block;
    background-color: #657A81;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    color: #FFF;
}
.menuitem:hover  {
    background-color: #AE7450;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
nav2 > h2 {display: none;}
nav2 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#hide_show {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#menuSX {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#Content3 {
    float: right;
    width: 69%;
}
.menubox {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

You can see it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stgjB/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the menu to collapse after clicking on one of the dropdowns, right?   The easiest way to accomplish this is by modifying this line:

```
  $('nav2>h2').click(function() {
```

And making it this:

```
  $('nav2>h2, .menuitem').click(function() {
```

What this means is that if you click on the h2 (the menu), or you click on one of the menu items, collapse it.

You can see the updated fiddle here:   **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stgjB/1/)**

Comment: Wow! Wonderful!! It was exactly what I was looking for!!!!!
Really thanks! I see it was so easy for you, but for me .... Thanks again.

Comment: @Mowgli - you are very welcome!   Glad to help...   please accept this as the accepted answer if you don't mind :)